# Django - Access fields on a model's "through" table from an instance

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship with a through table like so:

```
class Chapter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,)
    slides = models.ManyToManyField('Slide', blank=True, related_name='chapters', through='SlideOrder')
    # ...

class Slide(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255,)
    # ...

class SlideOrder(models.Model):
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter)
    slide = models.ForeignKey(Slide)
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

I am able to get the slides for a chapter in order like so:

```
chapter = Chapter.objects.get(pk=1)
chapter_slides = chapter.slides.order_by('slideorder')
```

However, when working on an individual slide instance I am unable to access the slide order:

```
slide = Slide.objects.get(pk=1)
```

If I do the following on my slide instance I can see all possible fields:

```
print slide._meta.get_all_field_names()
['title', u'chapters', 'slideorder', u'id']
```

However trying to access the `slideorder` field gives me the following:

```
slide.slideorder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Slide' object has no attribute 'slideorder'
```

I am able to access all attributes listed except `slideorder`.  How can I access a slide's order?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can either filter on the `SlideOrder` model directly

```
slide = Slide.objects.get(pk=1)
slide_orders = SlideOrder.objects.filter(slide=slide)
for slide_order in slide_orders:
    print slide_order.number
```

or follow the foreign key backwards:

```
slide = Slide.objects.get(pk=1)
slide_orders = slide.slideorder_set.all()
for slide_order in slide_orders:
    print slide_order.number
```

See the docs on [extra fields on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) for more info.

Comment: So the only way to get the slide order for a specific slide is to do 3 queries?  `chapter = Chapter.objects.get(pk=1), slide = Slide.objects.get(pk=1), slide_order = SlideOrder.objects.get(slide=slide, chapter=chapter), print slide_order.number`

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, you should be able to use [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) or [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related). For example `SlideOrder.objects.filter(slide=1, chapter=1).select_related('slide', 'chapter')` is one query.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `slide.slideorder_set` as documented in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)