# How to query the implicit through table in django (ManyToMany field)?

Tags: django, many-to-many

In the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) it reads the following:

> If you don’t specify an explicit through model, **there is still an**
>   **implicit through model class you can use to directly access the table**
>   **created to hold the association**.

However, I can not find out *how* I can access this table. Say I have this structure:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
```

And I would like to query the table that holds the person_groups (the implicit through table)... how do I do this?

```
PersonGroup.objects.all()
```

That does not work, and I can't find what syntax I should be using.

Comment: why do you need to access `PersonGroup`? in all major ORMs they take care of the third reference table for you when you're working with `ManyToMany` relationship, you shouldn't need to access the records from that table when you access your `ManyToMany` field ORM fetches appropriate records for you.

Comment: In my particular situation it is much more efficient to query `PersonGroup` directly and from what I understand this is possible so I am trying to understand how that works.

Comment: so you want to query the reference table using Django models?

Comment: tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31272862/6027876 ?

Comment: Yes I want to query the reference table. In the link provided it does not query this table directly. In the manual it specifically says there is a "through model class you can use to directly access the table", so my question is how to use that through model.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your case it'll be like `Group.members.through.objects.all()`

I.e. `Group.members.through` returns a model class like `<class 'appname.models.Group_person'>`

But I am still not sure that this will make your query more effective. You always can filter on one table, then filter its members or persons.

Comment: Great! That is it! I had to do some extra looping though the tables if I did it differently because of my particular use case. This works very well, thanks!

Comment: This is amazing! I never know there was such a thing.

Comment: Ok, after doing some testing, I found that this is ok if you're getting data **from the through table only**. If you try to access a field from a joined table, e.g. `field_id.id` it ends up running one query *per* row which isn't what you want. Using `prefetch_related` helps cut this down but if anyone has a better solution I'm all ears.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Same outer fields fetching rules as in any model also applied for through table. I guess `select_related` and `prefetch_related` are the only options here

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define the explicit through table if you want to access it through the ORM.

Given the way you've defined the relationship you have

```
person = Person.objects.get(id=x) 
groups = person.members_set.all()
```

and

```
groups = Group.objects.get(id=x)
members = group.members
```

Otherwise you'll need to access the table through [Raw SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/)

Comment: OK thanks, but then what does this sentence from the manual refer to:

"there is still an implicit through model class you can use to directly access the table created to hold the association"?

Comment: That's a grand question which I've never noticed - it implies I am wrong.  But I would suggest if you need to use the through table you should define it explicitly to make the code more readable if nothing else

Comment: Noted. If I have no other option then I'll create an explicit through but I'd really like to learn how to use this implicit through model.

Comment: Are you sure you cannot match performance times using `prefetch_related` and `select_related`?

Comment: Maybe but for now the direct querying is the easiest and fastest option and the other answer provided explains how to do it. Thanks for the info.